# Mapping a collection and a single navigation property that point to the same table

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

I have the following model:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("MainAddress")]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }

    // .. some more standard props that aren't keys/FKs etc

    [ForeignKey("MainAddress")]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string MainAddressCode { get; set; }

    [Include]
    [Association("Addresses", "CustomerNumber", "CustomerNumber")]
    public IList<CustomerAddress> Addresses { get; set; }

    [Include]
    [Association("MainAddress", "CustomerNumber,MainAddressCode", "CustomerNumber,CustomerAddressCode")]
    public CustomerAddress MainAddress { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerAddress
{
    public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }

    public string CustomerAddressCode { get; set; }

    // .. address props after this
}
```

I'd like to be able to get entity framework to retrieve the list of addresses for a customer, but also retrieve the main address using the `MainAddressCode` field in combination with `CustomerNumber`

At the moment the closest I can get is that the query generated looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[CustomerNumber] AS [CustomerNumber], 
    [Extent1].[CustomerName] AS [CustomerName], 
    [Extent1].[MainAddressCode] AS [MainAddressCode], 
    [Extent2].[CustomerNumber] AS [CustomerNumber1], 
    [Extent2].[CustomerAddressCode] AS [CustomerAddressCode], 
    [Extent2].[Customers_CustomerNumber] AS [Customer_CustomerNumber] <--- Argh!
    FROM  [dbo].[Customers] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CustomerAddress] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent1].[MainAddressCode] = [Extent2].[CustomerAddressCode]) AND ([Extent1].[CustomerNumber] = [Extent2].[CustomerNumber])
```

I'm think this is because EF is by convention prefixing the `Customer` entity name on the front of the FK for the `CustomerAddress` table.

How I can specify the column name of the foreign key on the `CustomerAddress` table so that the query executes correctly? Do I need to use the fluent API instead of attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with this:

```
var config = modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>();

        config.HasMany(x => x.Addresses)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(x => new { x.CustomerNumber });

        config.HasRequired(x => x.MainAddress)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => new { x.CustomerNumber, x.MainAddressCode });
```

Seems to work so far!